# asp.net mvc script and style references

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to include script and style references that will not break on deployment, however I can not even get the references to work locally. I have tried using `Url.Content()` and MVCContrib's `<%=Html.ScriptInclude("")%>`.

My scripts are in a Scripts folder on the root of the site; my styles are in the usual 
Content/css/ folder.

The scripts render like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.debug.js" ></script>
```

This will not work in a view page in the Views folder. What am I doing wrong and what is the best way to handle this?

I would have thought `Url.Content()` would at least work for styles but used in my master page, the link rendered

```
<link href="/Content/css/Site.css rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

This does not work, because the Master Page is in a Shared folder, so what is really the way forward with this?

Comment: Huh, odd... I thought I used Url.Content and it worked for me; at the bare minimum, you can always use ../../ because all of your views are always one folder deep within the views root folder (unless you customized the process).

Comment: true how ever if deployed as a virtual directory, as opposed to a website, would this not mess up the paths? there must be some way of managing this. I too am suprised that Url.Content does not work, oh, well!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<link href="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Content/css/Site.css")%>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /`>

works for your style sheet. but if you are on MVC2 and you have the files in the script dir then you can use the new helper:

```
<%=Html.Script("scriptfile.js") %>
```

this is better practice as you can also specify a file for release and debug mode:

```
<%=Html.Script("scriptfile-min.js", "scriptfile.js") %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this:

```
<link href="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Content/css/Site.css")%>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Also, take the runat=server out of your head tag if you don't want it trying to do you favors.

(Edit - fixed a misplaced quote)

**Update:** To clarify, I do in fact have this working in development (localhost:1227, root), on my test server (full domain, root) and in production (different domain, in a subdirectory). Works great in every case!